# Select on combination of two column values and there can be multiple sets

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table Test with say 4 columns:

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD
```

I want to write a query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Test WHERE (ColA = 1 AND ColB = 'A') OR (ColA =2 AND ColB = 'B') ..."
```

Is there a better way to write this query using "IN" in sqlite?

Comment: You can use **IN**, only on a field, not on combined fields. I.e.: `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE ColA IN (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64)`

Comment: hmmm, so this is the only way to write this query? This will get inefficient for a large number of combinations.

Comment: No, since it would do the same amount of comparisons. What you are really looking for is a way to compact the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table with these values, and join with it:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MyLittleSearch(ColA, ColB);
INSERT INTO MyLittleSearch VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO MyLittleSearch VALUES (2, 'B');
...

SELECT * FROM Test JOIN MyLittleSearch USING (ColA, ColB);

DROP TABLE MyLittleSearch;
```

This might be worth it if the number of seach records is really large, or constructed step by step.